# How can I pull twitter data directly into my website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I am attempting to collect Twitter data for specific areas. For example, I want a data feed from Twitter to my site which provides me with the number of tweets that occurred within the past hour. If I use Ruby's Twitter gem, I am able to search for Tweets by location, but I must require a search term. How can I pull twitter data directly into my rails app?

Comment: Twitter has both a [REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public) and a [Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview) why not just plug directly into those without a gem?

Comment: Your question is too broad. There are multiple ways to do this, but we don't know your code, abilities, preferences.

Comment: How do I use streaming API directly from a rails app? There exist plenty of instructions of how to do this from terminal but I am unsure how to do that in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

If you looking for streaming Twitter API, then you can use [twitter-stream](https://github.com/voloko/twitter-stream) gem. It's rather old, but will give you an idea of ​​the approach.